# migration failed. cannot drop table register_users and password_resets

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration

I have an issue when migrate database on laravel 5.4
I have created 3 table, users, register_users, and password_resets but the problem is when i migrate the database they only create users table but not the register_users and password_resets.

migrate error

[image]

database/table status

[image]

Comment: Sounds like the `migrations` table is out of sync from a previous error. Try running `php artisan migrate:rollback` or, if you don't care about losing data, `php artisan migrate:fresh`.

Comment: You should always include the errors as text in the question. not as pictures.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your `migrations` table is either missing, truncated or simply out of date with your setup. Your `users` table exists, but Laravel is trying to create it when you run `php artisan migrate`.

If this is just a local development environment and it's safe to do so, you could just drop your users table and run the command again. Use whatever you're comfortable with to do it, be it phpMyAdmin, MySQL workbench, or the command line etc. Then you just need to run your migration again.

If you are able to upgrade to using Laravel 5.5, there's a new command which could save you the hassle:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

That drops all of your tables in your schema and then runs your migrations from a "fresh" state.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i drop the database and then doing the migrate again. and its works

Answer (score 0):

if you can login to mysql, try to drop all tables including `migrations`, if it's localhost, then do it as following:

1. delete the database:

   `mysql -u root -e "drop database YOUR_DATABASE"`
2. recreate it:

   `mysql -u root -e "create database YOUR_DATABASE"`
3. run migration:

   `php artisan migrate`

Comment: thanks for the advice, i drop the database and then doing the migrate again. and its works

Comment: great then, sometimes laravel migration gets outdated